# How much to increment the Scrollbar position when the arrow buttons are clicked?

Tags: c, winapi

I am using a Scrollbar to scroll a bitmap.

When I click on the right or left arrow button, how much should I increment/decrement the Scrollbar position (I mean is there a convention that people use)? should it be only 1 unit?

Note that the range for the horizontal Scrollbar is the same as the width of the image (and the same goes for the vertical Scrollbar), and so when I increment the Scrollbar position by 1, I am shifting the image by 1 pixel.

Answer (score 2):

Above all, ensure the scrolling feels natural, and provides a good user experience.  Adjusting by 1 pixel will have varying results, which depend on the image size.

Try having a small unit of measurement, and a larger for paging (when the user clicks it the track region).  Try 1% of the corresponding width or height for small, and 5% for large.  That way the user will have a consistent experience, regardless of the image size.